# Django makemessages command warning: lone surrogate

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translate, django-i18n

I have a problem with django v4.2.
When I use the command `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l de` I get a bunch of lines of this:

```
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+D820
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+DC00
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+DFFF
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+D821
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+DC00
.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js:136: warning: lone surrogate U+DFEC
```

Not sure why that happens but I think that because of that, djangojs.po is not created and I need it to translate inside javascript.
Files:

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('admin/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('website.urls', namespace='website'))
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("jsi18n/", JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name="javascript-catalog"),
)

if 'rosetta' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls'))
    ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('hr', _('Hrvatski')),
    ('en', _('Engleski')),
    ('de', _('Njemački'))
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

I tried different combinations with the command and a bunch of similar things but even when I manage to get rid of those warnings djangojs.po is not created which is my goal.